# How to add content to ember component dynamically

Tags: javascript, ember.js, leaflet

I am writing a web application in ember.js for the first time. I'm using ember-leaflet in order to create a map, which is the main page of the application. The map is located in a component called main-map and looks like:

```
{{#leaflet-map lat=lat lng=lng zoom=zoom class="max-height" }}

  {{#each availableBasemaps as |basemap|}}
    {{#layer-group name=basemap.name default=basemap.default baselayer=true}}
      {{tile-layer url=basemap.url attribution=basemap.attrib}}
    {{/layer-group}}
  {{/each}}

  {{#each availableLayers as |lr|}}
    {{#layer-group name=lr.name default=lr.default}}
      {{wms-tile-layer url=lr.url version=lr.version layers=lr.layers format=lr.format styles=lr.styles transparent=lr.transparent}}
    {{/layer-group}}
  {{/each}}

  {{layer-control handler=(action "layerControlEvent")}}
{{/leaflet-map}}
```

This main-map component is located in my application.hbs so it is present in all routes in my website. In one route that I have, called search-address, I need to add a marker to the map based on the user input. The marker will look something like:

```
{{#marker-layer location=Location}}
   {{#popup-layer}}
     <h4> My address </h4>
   {{/popup-layer}}
 {{/marker-layer}}
```

I need a way to modify the main-map from within my search-address.js file in order to add these markers to my map. How can I accomplish this in Ember?

Answer (score 0):

Ember's `application` controller has `currentRouteName` property. Therefore you can reach current route's name in your `application.hbs` template or `application.js` controller anytime. In your case, in your `application.js`, you can define a computed property such as:

```
inSearchAddress: Ember.computed('currentRouteName', function(){
    return this.get('currentRouteName') === 'search-address';
})
```

And in your `application.hbs`, you can pass this computed property to your `main-map` component such as `{{main-map inSearchAddress=inSearchAddress}}` and then use it in the component like:

```
{{#if inSearchAddress}}
    {{#marker-layer location=Location}}
        {{#popup-layer}}
           <h4> My address </h4>
        {{/popup-layer}}
     {{/marker-layer}}
{{/if}}
```

You can also take a look at this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/#/25950c46918df36c9089ab0b12b7cec5) for this usage.

Comment: Actually I realized this wouldn't work because that {{#if inSearchAddress}} block would really need to be in my main-map.hbs, meaning that the inSearchAddress computed property would need to be in main-map.js. Is there still a way to get the current route name outside of application controller? Thanks!

Comment: @JackieM You can define computed property in your application.hbs and pass it to your component. I have updated my answer and my twiddle according to your comment.

Comment: `currentRouteName` is also a property on the new Router service that was added in Ember 2.15

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a singleton service, named say `locationService`, to hold the data.

Are you adding locations to an existing list? If so, have some key called `locationsToRender` on said service and in your application template:

`{{#each locationService.locationsToRender as |location|}}
  {{#marker-layer location=location}}
     {{#popup-layer}}
       <h4> My address </h4>
     {{/popup-layer}}
   {{/marker-layer}}
{{/each}}`

And then in that route, simply `pushObject` to said array.

Instead, if you want to stop showing all other pins and only show that pin, then have some function on that service that toggles some variable that hides all other layers and just shows that layer `locationService.showSearchAddress(location)`